# Is there a way for LaTeX to always return?

Tags: pdftex

I'm currently writing a Python program that can automate detection of whether a certain command is permitted in math mode without using any packages.

For the purpose of testing I add `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}$` before a command to be tested and `$\end{document}` after it. Then I save it to a file using a randomly generated filename and use `latex <filename>+'.tex'` to TeX the file.

If the command is actually permitted the process ends and I can obtain a return code of 0. On the other hand when TeXing doesn't work instead of returning an error code the process simply doesn't end.

Is there a way to run LaTeX so that the process always return even if there is an error?

Comment: Nevermind. There is `-halt-on-error `. Problem solved!

Comment: Not really. There are cases where this does not work for unknown reasons. I really don't want to put some form of timeout there since it will be machine-dependent.

Comment: most editors will get some error feedback when run using one of the nonstop options run (pdf)latex --help to see most choices especially -interaction=errorstopmode and nonstopmode

Comment: "machine dependent" should be fairly trivial all windows should respond to taskkill should be similar kill for *nix ? the timer is dwn to the app

Comment: you can quite easily write tex code that runs a long time: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiling. So without some timeout it will not work.

Comment: Off topic ish, but I believe you can just call `latex \documentclass{article}\begin{document}$\command$\end{document}` (and figure out the slashes appropriately).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well I will only test a single glyph at a time so that's not a problem.

Comment: since you are not loading any packages why do you need a python program, there is a fixed list of commands and a fixed subset of them that work in math mode

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh? Then I would like to see that list. I don't really need it any more though. Instead I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4):

It's trivial to write a TeX program that results in an infinite loop. As such, one cannot be certain that a job will finish. Typically, automated systems address this by looking for some output over a given time frame, and likely a maximum run time after which a job is killed. Those aspects are of course out-of-scope for this particular site.